# Construction a Lyapunov Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am struggling on answering the following question. My lecturer rushed the explanation and his notes are very vague about it. The question is:

$$
\dot x = -x+2y^3-2y^4
$$
$$
\dot y = -x-y+xy
$$

Show the above has no closed orbits by constructing a Lyapunov function $V=x^m+ay^n$ where $a,m,n$ are to be found.

I know the first step would be to find $\dot V$ which is, in my case, given by $\dot V = mx^{m-1}(-x+2y^3-2y^4)+nay^{n-1}(-x-y+xy)$ but I'm unsure on what the next step is.

Thanks

Comment: "what the next step is" Try to cancel as many terms of undetermined sign as possible in $\dot V$.

Comment: my issue is that if i expand this, I still end up with a 6 term equation and i'm not sure what to do with it

Comment: Of course you "end up" with six terms since there are six terms... and then, as I said, the game is to choose $(n,m,a)$ such that some of them are cancelling one another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have said, we have:$$\dot{V} = mx^{m-1}(-x+2y^3-2y^4)+nay^{n-1}(-x-y+xy).$$ Expanding this we'll get:
$$\dot{V} = -mx^{m}+2mx^{m-1}y^3-2mx^{m-1}y^4-anxy^{n-1}-any^n+anxy^n.$$
For a Lyapunov function we want that it is decreasing along orbits, i.e. here $\dot{V} \leq 0.$ So this is what we're going to aim for when finding $a$, $n$ and $m$.

We can tell straight away that we'll want some of the terms to cancel, so that we can guarantee a non-positive gradient for $V$. So first we try $n=4$  (we match $n$ to the powers of $y$ that we already know). This gives us:

$$\dot{V} = -mx^{m}+2mx^{m-1}y^3-2mx^{m-1}y^4-4axy^3-4ay^4+4axy^4$$

Doing the same thing, we take $m = 2$, which gives:

$$\dot{V} = -2x^2+4xy^3-4xy^4-4axy^3-4ay^4+4axy^4.$$

We can now see that if we take $a = 1$ then we get that $V$ is a Lyapunov function, as required, since then:

$$\dot{V} = -2x^2+4xy^3-4xy^4-4xy^3-4y^4+4xy^4 = -2x^2-4y^4 \leq 0 \text{ for all $x$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^2$.}$$

Comment: ah yes that's perfect, I didn't think to try to make the powers the same. thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome!